# pulling the list of values from the list of keys

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have a record as

```
firstMap = [ name1:[ value1:10, value2:'name1', value3:150, value4:20 ],
             name2:[ value1:10, value2:'name2', value3:150, value4:20 ] ]
```

I have a list where the values are name1, name2, etc.

I want to pull the list depending on the name1 as

```
[ name1:[ value1:10, value2:'name1', value3:150, value4:20 ]
```

`firstMap.subMap(["name1"])`, did work for me, but I have a list and by looping the list I need to pull the values

```
namesList.each{record ->
    newMap = firstmap.subMap(record)
}
```

I have tried subMap([offer]), subMap(["offer"]), subMap(["offer?.stringValue()"]), subMap(['offer']), etc. But none of them work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need submap at all, that's only really useful when you want to grab a few keys at once or if you need the original key in the result

Try:

```
firstMap = [ name1:[ value1:10, value2:'name1', value3:150, value4:20 ],
             name2:[ value1:10, value2:'name2', value3:150, value4:20 ] ]

def namesList = [ 'name1', 'name2' ]

namesList.each { name ->
    println firstMap[ name ]
}
```

Or if you need a Map result with the original query key:

```
namesList.each { name ->
    println firstMap.subMap( [ name ] )
}
```

Or indeed:

```
namesList.each { name ->
    println( [ (name):firstMap[ name ] ] )
}
```

Would give you the same (ie: create a new map with the key `name` and the value of my first example)

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried the last two ways, but its not yielding me the result :-( the output is [name1:null], but when I just check it for one of the values of the namesList as firstMap.subMap(["name1"]) it is displaying properly as ["name1":["val1":10, ....]]

Comment: @Techie Are you trying exactly my example code above?  Or are you trying to run the above with your own code, and making your own `namesList` of Groovy Templated Strings?  Sounds like the latter. Groovy Strings _are not Strings_ so looking up keys defined as Strings with Groovy Strings isn't going to work.  Try `firstMap.subMap( [ name.toString() ] )`

Comment: Yes Tim, thanks for specifying that...it seems working...thanks a ton as always...

Comment: Hi Tim, while doing this, when there are two keys with the same value in namesList as [name1, name1] then the first entry is being overwritten, I want to preserve both of them. how do I do that?

Comment: That would mean you have two identical keys in the Map wouldn't it?  Which can't happen...

Comment: Is there any alternative way of handling this?

Comment: It depends on your inputs and required outputs.  This works for the example given.  If you can alter the example to show a simple situation where it doesn't work (preferably not your actual data, as it makes me code-blind) ;-)

Comment: I understand that Tim, actually my code is completely different and I am just trying to provide examples as a glimpse of my code hmmm :-) I will try to provide the input in a better way soon