# setting values of one map to other depending on a condition

Tags: groovy

I have couple of records rec1 and rec2.

Both are having a common key/value name1.

when the name1 is equal in both the records then I need to set few values of rec2 to rec1.

I put them into two different loops as below

```
rec1.each{r1-> each
    rec2.each{r2-> each
        if(r2.name1 == r1.name1){
        r1.name2 = r2.name2
        r1.name3 = r2.name3
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this

Example : (sorry I am just pasting the contents)

> recoRecord  : [["CHANNEL":INBOUND, "STOCK_LEVEL":2410.0,
>   "OFFER_TARIFF_ID":FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-31-24-04, "P_BAND":P4-6,
>   "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":10.0,
>   "HANDSET_PKEY_ID":SAM-STD-I9300-1, "CUST_TYPE":MEDIA]]
>
> records : [["MEDIA_SUBSIDY_VALUE":0.0, "CREDIT_CLASS":C5,
>   "DOM_OTHER_MARGIN":0.0, "isBatchTerminator":false,
>   "CALL_GROUP_DESC":COMBINED, "DM":20.0, "BLACKBERRY_IND":N,
>   "PREFERRED_BLACKBERRY":N, "ERROR_ID":0, "CUST_TYPE":MEDIA,
>   "TARIFF_MRC":30.99, "MOST_USED_TAC":35961404, "FORM_FACTOR":null,
>   "CAMERA_IND":null, "NEW_MARGIN":22.272501, "MODEL":null,
>   "IS_MMS_ALLOWANCE":N, "ACTIVE_HANDSET_BANDS":,
>   "CUST_OUT_OF_ALLOWANCE_PLAN":JV15, "OOB_DOM_VOICE":0.0,
>   "OOB_DOM_SMS":0.0, "VM_CUST_FLAG":Y, "IB_DATA":0.0,
>   "CHANNEL_FLAG":INBOUND, "SMS_ALLOWANCE":5000.0, "ROAM_SMS_MARGIN":0.0,
>   "TARIFF_DESC":30.99 Virgin Media 24 month+1GB 1300mins,
>   "MARGIN_CHANGE_PCT":0.12691319, "OFFER_VOICE_ALLOWANCE":600,
>   "MAKE":null, "IS_ONNET_ALLOWANCE":Y, "OFFER_CONTRACT_TERM":24.0,
>   "PREFERRED_MINUTES":1300, "PREFERRED_ON_NET":Y,
>   "MOST_USED_IMEI":359614048625860, "DISCOUNT":3.0,
>   "NetPresentValue":1.15, "RecInd":1, "WIFI_IND":null, "IPHONE_IND":N,
>   "OFFER_TARIFF_ID":FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-31-24-04,
>   "IncentivePoints":-1.0]

when OFFER_TARIFF_ID in both the records are same then I would like to set few values of first record to second record

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and expected output?

Comment: sure, will edit my question

Comment: Also I have given a comment to one of my previous questions you answered...could you  please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610469/pulling-the-list-of-values-from-the-list-of-keys

Comment: Again, that's not valid Groovy...  I meant an example which I could run, and maybe something cut down a bit so we can see what's going on...  Also, the expected output...

Comment: It did work for me, just looking for a better way of implementing it, Thanks Tim.

Comment: It would help if the maps you provided were valid groovy though, you have the keys in quotes and not the values, and I'm not sure if `records :` is supposed to be `records =`

Comment: Oh my mistake, I just pasted my logs there(output) not my code, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over both the maps. Just need to check the value of that particular key matches or not.

```
if(r2.'OFFER_TARIFF_ID' == r1.'OFFER_TARIFF_ID'){
  //push the required entries from r1 to r2
}
```

Although in your edit, I do not see a valid data structure for records, I considered r1 and r2 as Maps.